# Serverless AWS redeployment error: S3 bucket already exists error, only for certain environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, serverless

I'm trying to deploy my Serverless project for several environments. I would like to run a develop, staging and production environment. To make this work I'm using `serverless-dotenv-plugin` with a `NODE_ENV=development` or `NODE_ENV=acceptation` (in this case). Everything related to the plugin works.

Everything related to the plugin seems to work. When I deploy for development or acceptance it loads the correct `.env` file, as well it does try to create the related S3 buckets.

[image: AWS Buckets]

As you can see in the attached image there are two buckets for each environment which I want to link to a Route53 domain. The initial deployment created the correct buckets. When I now deploy again, **for development there is no issue**. Although when I deploy for acceptance I get the error `An error occurred: BucketGatsbySite - project-bucket-acc-www-gatsby already exists.`, **so the build breaks**.

Of course the bucket already exists, but because it's already created it shouldn't be re-created. This seems to work for development, but not for acceptance and I have no clue why. In this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html) I can't find anything related to this. Although as you can see below I do have the `DeletionPolicy: Retain`, which I think should mean there shouldn't be a new one created, but the old one should be retained.

So to summarise, I want to create a bucket but not overwrite it. Only create it once and after that retain the old ones and don't try to create new ones.

My config is as follows:

```yaml
service: project

package:
  individually: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  stage: ${env:STAGE}
  region: ${env:REGION}
  environment:
    REGION: ${env:REGION}
    STAGE: ${env:STAGE}
    NODE_ENV: ${env:NODE_ENV}
    CLIENT_ID: ${env:AWS_CLIENT_ID}
    TABLE: "project-db-${env:STAGE}"
    BUCKET: "project-bucket-${env:STAGE}"
    POOL: "project-userpool-${env:STAGE}"
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:*
          Resource:
            - !GetAtt projectTable.Arn

BucketReactApp:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    AccessControl: PublicRead
    BucketName: "${self:provider.environment.BUCKET}-www-react"
BucketGatsbySite:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    AccessControl: PublicRead
    BucketName: "${self:provider.environment.BUCKET}-www-gatsby"
```

Every suggestion would be really appreciated, since I'm kinda stuck on this..

Answer (score 0):

Some changes in CloudFormation (CFN) require update of the resource. It's mentioned on the ["AWS::S3::Bucket"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html) documentation page as `Update requires` property for each statement.

And here is the list of all ["Update behaviors of stack resources"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html) and `Replacement` will means that the bucket will be recreated.

But it's still strange, because the only two statements that require replacement on update are:

- BucketName
- ObjectLockEnabled

So maybe some intermediate operation on CFN stack requires recreation of S3 bucket.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should be looking at the **UpdateReplacePolicy** attribute:

```
BucketGatsbySite:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  ...
  UpdateReplacePolicy:
```

link: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: I tried UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain but sadly it still tried to create the s3 bucket and then fails